# Python code stops running after I start my threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm Trying to make a simple clicker game with pygame, and I'm trying to add a text that says '+1' when you click the button, but so it doesn't delay the code, I wanna put it in a second thread. I tried this but when i start both of the threads, the code just stops without any error messages or anything.

Here's The Code:

```
#Imports
from numerize import numerize
import schedule
import pygame
import time
from time import sleep
import sys
import random
import threading

#All The Variables#
running = True
SmallFuncRunning = True
#colors
red = (255, 45, 0)
orange = (255, 173, 0)
yellow = (255, 245, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
light_blue = (0, 255, 230)
blue = (0, 0, 128)
purple = (140, 0, 255)
pink = (255, 0, 243)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
#windows
number_position = 125, 100
image_size = 500, 400
text_size = 32
image_place = 0, 0
windows_one_size = 250, 400
#animals
cat_count = 0
cat_price = 60
cat_EPS = cat_count * 1
dog_count = 0
dog_price = 100
dog_EPS = dog_count * 2
eagle_count = 0
eagle_price = 1000
eagle_EPS = eagle_count * 25
human_count = 0
human_price = 3500
human_EPS = human_count * 100
#numbers
UpgradePrice = 100
EPC = 1
number = 0



#Fuctions
#save numbers


def save_to_file_number():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_number.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(number))

def save_to_file_EPC():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_EPC.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(EPC))

def save_to_file_UpgradePrice():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_UP.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(UpgradePrice))

def save_to_file_cat_count():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_catcount.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(cat_count))

def save_to_file_dog_count():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogcount.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(dog_count))

def save_to_file_eagle_count():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_eaglecount.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(eagle_count))

def save_to_file_human_count():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_humancount.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(human_count))

def save_to_file_cat_price():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_catprice.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(cat_price))

def save_to_file_dog_price():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogprice.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(dog_price))

def save_to_file_eagle_price():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_eagleprice.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(eagle_price))

def save_to_file_human_price():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_humanprice.txt', 'a') as text:
        text.truncate(1)
        text.write(str(human_price))

#save all
def save_all():
    save_to_file_EPC()
    save_to_file_number()
    save_to_file_UpgradePrice()
    save_to_file_cat_count()
    save_to_file_dog_count()
    save_to_file_eagle_count()
    save_to_file_human_count()
    save_to_file_dog_price()
    save_to_file_cat_price()
    save_to_file_eagle_price()
    save_to_file_human_price()


#Pygame Initialize / Updating
pygame.init()

with open('Saves.txts/Save_humanprice.txt')as f:
    human_price = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_humancount.txt')as f:
    human_count = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_eagleprice.txt')as f:
    eagle_price = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_eaglecount.txt')as f:
    eagle_count = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogprice.txt')as f:
    dog_price = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogcount.txt')as f:
    dog_count = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_catprice.txt')as f:
    cat_price = str(round(float(f.read())))
if cat_price != 30 or 36 or 33 or 39:
    cat_price = cat_price[1:]
with open('Saves.txts/Save_catcount.txt')as f:
    cat_count = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_UP.txt')as f:
    UP = round(float(f.read()))
with open('Saves.txts/Save_EPC.txt')as f:
    EPC = f.read()
    EPC = int(EPC[1:])

#Backround
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((image_size))

#Window 1
pygame.display.set_caption('BadClickerGameLOL')
Window1 = pygame.image.load('Pictures/Window1.jpg')
Window1 = pygame.transform.scale(Window1, (windows_one_size))
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', text_size)

#Window 2
Window2 = pygame.image.load('Pictures/Shop.jpg')
Window2 = pygame.transform.scale(Window2, (250, 200))

#Window 3
Window3 = pygame.image.load('Pictures/Shop.jpg')
Window3 = pygame.transform.scale(Window2, (250, 200))



#Number/Windows/EPC

def PlusOneText():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                PlusOne = font.render('+' + str(EPC), True, (42, 92, 222))
                screen.blit(PlusOne, (random.randint(25, 150), random.randint(25, 150)))
                pygame.display.update()

def MainFunc():
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_humanprice.txt')as f:
        human_price = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_humancount.txt')as f:
        human_count = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_eagleprice.txt')as f:
        eagle_price = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_eaglecount.txt')as f:
        eagle_count = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogprice.txt')as f:
        dog_price = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogcount.txt')as f:
        dog_count = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_catprice.txt')as f:
        cat_price = str(round(float(f.read())))
    if cat_price != 30 or 36 or 33 or 39:
        cat_price = cat_price[1:]
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_catcount.txt')as f:
        cat_count = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_UP.txt')as f:
        UP = round(float(f.read()))
    with open('Saves.txts/Save_EPC.txt')as f:
        EPC = f.read()
        EPC = int(EPC[1:])
        running = True
    while running:
        with open('Saves.txts/Save_number.txt') as f:
            number = int(f.read())
        f.close()
        CompactNumber = numerize.numerize(number)
        schedule.run_pending()
        text = font.render(str(CompactNumber), True, (42, 92, 222))
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(number_position))
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        screen.blit(Window1, (image_place))
        screen.blit(text, (text_rect))
        screen.blit(Window2, (251, 0))
        screen.blit(Window3, (251, 201))
        pygame.display.update()
        #skeypressing
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        #Keypressing ifs
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        save_all()
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_number.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(0))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_EPC.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(1))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_UP.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(100))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_catcount.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(0))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogcount.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(0))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_eaglecount.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(0))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_humancount.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(0))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_catprice.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(60))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_dogprice.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(100))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_eagleprice.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(1000))
                        with open('Saves.txts/Save_humanprice.txt', 'a') as text:
                            text.truncate(1)
                            text.write(str(3500))
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        if number >= int(cat_price):
                            number -= int(cat_price)
                            cat_count += 1
                            
                            cat_price = float(int(cat_price) * 1.1)
                            print("The next cat price is " + str(int(cat_price)))
                            EPS += 1
                            save_to_file_EPS()
                            save_to_file_cat_count()
                            save_to_file_cat_price()
                            save_to_file_number()
                        else:
                            print('Insufficient Energy!')
                            print("You need " + str(int(cat_price)) + " to buy a cat!")
    
                    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        if number >= dog_price:
                            number -= int(dog_price)
                            dog_count += 1
                            dog_price = int(dog_price * 1.1)
                            print("The next dog price is " + str(dog_price))
                            EPS += 2
                            save_to_file_EPS()
                            save_to_file_dog_count()
                            save_to_file_dog_price()
                            save_to_file_number()
                        else:
                            print('Insufficient Energy!')
                            print("You need " + str(dog_price) + " to buy a dog")
    
                    if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                        if number >= eagle_price:
                            number -= int(eagle_price)
                            eagle_count += 1
                            eagle_price = int(eagle_price * 1.1)
                            print("The next dog price is " + str(eagle_price))
                            EPS += 25
                            save_to_file_EPS()
                            save_to_file_eagle_count()
                            save_to_file_eagle_price()
                            save_to_file_number()
                        else:
                            print('Insufficient Energy!')
                            print("You need " + str(eagle_price) + " to buy an eagle")
    
                    if event.key == pygame.K_h:
                        if number >= human_price:
                            number -= int(human_price)
                            human_count += 1
                            human_price = int(human_price * 1.1)
                            print("The next human price is " + str(human_price))
                            EPS += 100
                            save_to_file_EPS()
                            save_to_file_human_count()
                            save_to_file_human_price()
                            save_to_file_number()
                        else:
                            print('Insufficient Energy!')
                            print("You need " + str(human_price) + " to buy a human")
    
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        number += int(EPC)
                        save_to_file_number()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_u:
                        if number >= UpgradePrice:
                            number -= int(UpgradePrice)
                            UpgradePrice = int(UpgradePrice*1.6)
                            print("The next Clicker Upgrade price is " + str(UpgradePrice))
                            EPC +=1
                            
                        if number <= UpgradePrice:
                            print('You Need ' + str(int(UpgradePrice)) + ' To Buy Another Clicker Upgrade!')
                            
                            save_to_file_EPC()
                            save_to_file_number()
                            save_to_file_UpgradePrice() 
                        else:
                            print('Insufficient Energy!')
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                save_all()
                sys.exit()

threading.Thread(target=MainFunc).start()
threading.Thread(target=PlusOneText).start()
```

Comment: does main thread execute past the `.start()` calls? or does it blocks  as you say?

Comment: @Blomex I just tried, if you put code behind the .start() calls, it does print it

Comment: You can't hijack events from the main cycle, you have to do it another way.

Comment: @Andrii what does hijacking events mean?

Comment: @MagicTax, I mean 'intercept'